# No puedo insertar contenido encriptado a base de datos

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando una clase de PHP para encriptar información, pero el resultado de la encriptacion, tiene caracteres como `Ѡ�Hf�{h������` no permitido en la inserción a mi base de datos con MySQL.
Esta es la clase PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * A class to handle secure encryption and decryption of arbitrary data
 *
 * Note that this is not just straight encryption.  It also has a few other
 *  features in it to make the encrypted data far more secure.  Note that any
 *  other implementations used to decrypt data will have to do the same exact
 *  operations.  
 *
 * Security Benefits:
 *
 * - Uses Key stretching
 * - Hides the Initialization Vector
 * - Does HMAC verification of source data
 *
 */
class Encryption {

    /**
     * @var string $cipher The mcrypt cipher to use for this instance
     */
    protected $cipher = '';

    /**
     * @var int $mode The mcrypt cipher mode to use
     */
    protected $mode = '';

    /**
     * @var int $rounds The number of rounds to feed into PBKDF2 for key generation
     */
    protected $rounds = 10000;

    /**
     * Constructor!
     *
     * @param string $cipher The MCRYPT_* cypher to use for this instance
     * @param int    $mode   The MCRYPT_MODE_* mode to use for this instance
     * @param int    $rounds The number of PBKDF2 rounds to do on the key
     */
    public function __construct($cipher, $mode, $rounds = 100) {
        $this->cipher = $cipher;
        $this->mode = $mode;
        $this->rounds = (int) $rounds;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt the data with the provided key
     *
     * @param string $data The encrypted datat to decrypt
     * @param string $key  The key to use for decryption
     * 
     * @returns string|false The returned string if decryption is successful
     *                           false if it is not
     */
    public function decrypt($data, $key) {
        $salt = substr($data, 0, 128);
        $enc = substr($data, 128, -64);
        $mac = substr($data, -64);

        list ($cipherKey, $macKey, $iv) = $this->getKeys($salt, $key);

        if (!hash_equals(hash_hmac('sha512', $enc, $macKey, true), $mac)) {
             return false;
        }

        $dec = mcrypt_decrypt($this->cipher, $cipherKey, $enc, $this->mode, $iv);

        $data = $this->unpad($dec);

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt the supplied data using the supplied key
     * 
     * @param string $data The data to encrypt
     * @param string $key  The key to encrypt with
     *
     * @returns string The encrypted data
     */
    public function encrypt($data, $key) {
        $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(128, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        list ($cipherKey, $macKey, $iv) = $this->getKeys($salt, $key);

        $data = $this->pad($data);

        $enc = mcrypt_encrypt($this->cipher, $cipherKey, $data, $this->mode, $iv);

        $mac = hash_hmac('sha512', $enc, $macKey, true);
        return $salt . $enc . $mac;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a set of keys given a random salt and a master key
     *
     * @param string $salt A random string to change the keys each encryption
     * @param string $key  The supplied key to encrypt with
     *
     * @returns array An array of keys (a cipher key, a mac key, and a IV)
     */
    protected function getKeys($salt, $key) {
        $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->cipher, $this->mode);
        $keySize = mcrypt_get_key_size($this->cipher, $this->mode);
        $length = 2 * $keySize + $ivSize;

        $key = $this->pbkdf2('sha512', $key, $salt, $this->rounds, $length);

        $cipherKey = substr($key, 0, $keySize);
        $macKey = substr($key, $keySize, $keySize);
        $iv = substr($key, 2 * $keySize);
        return array($cipherKey, $macKey, $iv);
    }

    /**
     * Stretch the key using the PBKDF2 algorithm
     *
     * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2
     *
     * @param string $algo   The algorithm to use
     * @param string $key    The key to stretch
     * @param string $salt   A random salt
     * @param int    $rounds The number of rounds to derive
     * @param int    $length The length of the output key
     *
     * @returns string The derived key.
     */
    protected function pbkdf2($algo, $key, $salt, $rounds, $length) {
        $size   = strlen(hash($algo, '', true));
        $len    = ceil($length / $size);
        $result = '';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
            $tmp = hash_hmac($algo, $salt . pack('N', $i), $key, true);
            $res = $tmp;
            for ($j = 1; $j < $rounds; $j++) {
                 $tmp  = hash_hmac($algo, $tmp, $key, true);
                 $res ^= $tmp;
            }
            $result .= $res;
        }
        return substr($result, 0, $length);
    }

    protected function pad($data) {
        $length = mcrypt_get_block_size($this->cipher, $this->mode);
        $padAmount = $length - strlen($data) % $length;
        if ($padAmount == 0) {
            $padAmount = $length;
        }
        return $data . str_repeat(chr($padAmount), $padAmount);
    }

    protected function unpad($data) {
        $length = mcrypt_get_block_size($this->cipher, $this->mode);
        $last = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
        if ($last > $length) return false;
        if (substr($data, -1 * $last) !== str_repeat(chr($last), $last)) {
            return false;
        }
        return substr($data, 0, -1 * $last);
    }
}
?>
```

Para encriptar, el código es el siguiente:

```
$e = new Encryption(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$encryptedData = $e->encrypt($data, $key);
```

Para desencriptar, el código es el siguiente:

```
$e2 = new Encryption(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$decryptedData = $e2->decrypt($encryptedData, $key);
```

Cuando intento insertar el contenido de `$encryptedData` en mi base de datos, resulta en error:

> 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD+\xDF\xB9...'

**Actualización**

Ejecuté estos comandos :

```
mysql> show variables like '%colla%';
mysql> show variables like '%charac%';
```

y me generaron estos valores:

```
collation_connection : utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
collation_database : utf8_spanish_ci 
collation_server : latin1_sweddish_ci
```

Alguno, que por favor pueda ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: has definido el formato en la tabla como UTF-8 ?

Comment: @fredyfx utf8_spanish_ci

Comment: ejecuta esto en el mysql:

Comment: mysql> show variables like '%colla%';

Comment: mysql> show variables like '%charac%';

Comment: y agrega ese dato a tu pregunta, de tal manera que verificamos y sale una mejor respuesta :D

Comment: `collation_connection : utf8mb4_unicode_ci` - `collation_database : utf8_spanish_ci` - `collation_server : latin1_sweddish_ci`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La única solución pronta y pues, no sé que tan optimizada o segura sea, es usando base64_encode() y base64_decode().

Se inserta a la base de datos:

```
$b64 = base64_encode($encryptedData);
```

Y cuando desee extraerse de la base de datos:

```
$b64 = base64_decode($encryptedData);
```

A mí me funcionó, y evité el conflicto con los carácteres especiales e ilegibles de la clase de encriptación.

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta en el `MySql`

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Luego verifica que las tablas donde la data esta siendo guardada tenga el set de caracteres UTF8:

```
SELECT
  `tables`.`TABLE_NAME`,
  `collations`.`character_set_name`
FROM
  `information_schema`.`TABLES` AS `tables`,
  `information_schema`.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` AS `collations`
WHERE
  `tables`.`table_schema` = DATABASE()
  AND `collations`.`collation_name` = `tables`.`table_collation`
;
```

Finalmente revisa los valores de la configuracion de la base de datos:

```
mysql> show variables like '%colla%';
mysql> show variables like '%charac%';
```

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013986/3613462

Comment: Tengo un nuevo problema, y es que caracteres como `Ê2L�#sggg3���k�����f�9�d�iȠ` entran en la base de datos, pero cuando voy a revisar de qué forma fue almacenada la información, en la base de datos está asi `Ê2L?#sggg3???k?????f?9?d?iȠ<y?k^͠.?aγZp%/{????!???????ܭH?2
?a??fXO}?Q??F?̓?Q+N???c?????{?"G???l?U
?K??:E????x?5QaLR????+g?r(ܥ1??E??T??#?n#?????5@?;?ͳ??M?.?y?aV??+8;}W` entonces, al ejecutar el código para desencriptar, no funciona. Hay algún código para transformar el string encriptado al formato en el que se recibe en mi base de datos?

Comment: que idiomas acepta tu aplicación? en el MySql, el campo donde se almacena esa información es varchar o nvarchar? Revisa estos 3 enlaces http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types/nvarchar_n http://arunthecodebehind.blogspot.in/2015/11/varchar-vs-nvarchar.html y http://stackoverflow.com/a/27100843/3613462

Comment: Pero varchar no puede ser, porque para textos grandes e inclusive cortos superan los 255 caracteres cuando se encripta. Es tipo LongText

Comment: Basado de la tabla: http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types NVARCHAR -> Sí tiene soporte para UTF8 a diferencia de LongText que parece ser que nop, tanta información en un campo así?

Comment: Dejame reviso el pma

Comment: Acabo de convertir mi columna en una varchar(10000) cosa que es rara, pero funcionó la conversion a ese varchar, el punto es que aún siguen cambiandose los caracteres...No los deja tal y como son insertados. Pero si lo hago de forma manual en PMA, no hay ningún problema en su inserción pero tampoco desencripta.

Comment: varchar? era Nvarchar!

Comment: No existe NVARCHAR en mi PMA.